# Trying to Create a Graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, subplot

I can create a graph using Jupyter however when I write this code using Python 3.6.4 shell I received the following:

> > > `enter code here

```
`File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
 File "C:\Users\RJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 144, in main
ret = method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\RJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 474, in runcode
exec(code, self.locals)
```

File "", line 1, in 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGkkX.png)

Comment: We need more information to help you here. First, make sure you always post the stacktrace. Second, I'd like to see what all the columns of `df` are. Show the output of `print(df.columns)`.

Comment: Thank you so much....I am trying to locate the stacktrace.

Comment: Here are the columns:>>> print(df.columns)
Index(['Date', 'Trips over the past 24-hours (midnight to 11:59pm)',
       'Miles traveled today (midnight to 11:59 pm)',
       'Total Annual Members (All Time)',
       '24-Hour Passes Purchased (midnight to 11:59 pm)',
       '3-Day Passes Purchased (midnight to 11:59 pm)'],
      dtype='object')

Comment: Okay, the column names seem fine. If you share the stacktrace we can identify the issue.

Comment: File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\RJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 144, in main
    ret = method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\RJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 474, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<pyshell#25>", line 1, in <module>

Comment: Can you edit the main post to share the stacktrace?

Comment: That isn't the full stacktrace that you shared, is it? Because that still isn't useful. Can you share a screenshot of what you are doing?

Comment: It is because I just started the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what the problem is. Firstly, you don't actually have any error. Change your lines to the following:

```
sns_plot = sns.distplot(df["24-Hour Passes Purchased (midnight to 11:59pm)"])
sns_plot.savefig("output.png")
```

Then you'll find a file on disk with the name "output.png" that you can see the plot in.

When I initially said that you should show the traceback error, I thought `sns.distplot` was throwing an error. That is not the case here. So you don't need to import traceback and print a traceback, since there was never any exception raised by the Python interpreter.

Secondly, you should consider using a Jupyter Notebook, since it'll make this process more interactive.

Hope that helps!

Comment: It does, and many thanks for the advice.  I am using Jupyter but thought going this route would be suitable to present to others later.   I pip installed just about all the packages I could think needed for data visualization.

Once more, thank you.

Comment: Great! Let me know if you have other questions. Also, please mark answers as accepted if they answer your question.

Comment: You're awesome.  I will pick your brain more.  I have a lot to learn and really appreciate it.